# MSW2012R2 StorageSpaces + SSD tiering. Unknown Placement Status

Tags: windows-server-2012, ssd, storage-spaces

I use StorageSpaces with tiering. I have several vhdx images that I want to be constantly pinned to SSD on my tier. I use command:

```
Set-FileStorageTier –FilePath "path" -DesiredStorageTier "tier"
```

Then I manually start optimize-volume command. After it's completed I see that some files are "On Tier", but after some time all of my vhdx files change "PlacementStatus" to "Unknown".

Does anyone what's going on? I can't see any errors in EventLog in StorageTiering section.

[image: status unknown]